# c# app not loading user settings

Tags: c#, winforms, settings.settings

I'm doing a WinForm application, and I've a form which has two TextBoxes, I'm loading values from `Settings.Default` on form load, like this:

```
txtUsername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default["email_username"].ToString();
txtAddress.Text = Properties.Settings.Default["physical_address"].ToString();
```

and I'm saving values back to `Settings.Default` and then dispose the form when user clicks a button, like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["email_username"] = txtUsername.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default["physical_address"] = txtAddress.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

When I close (dispose) the form and then open it again (application still running), I can load settings normally. However, if I close the application then I open the form again (I'm expecting to find data loaded) I find that data is loaded into **ONE** TextBox but not the other one, which is odd!

Please note that I've tried the following but the same problem still occurs:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.email_username = txtUsername.Text;
```

Also, I've tried *Application Settings*'s (Property Binding), but same problem occurs!

NB: when I've debugged the application, I found that it's loading empty `""` data into one of the TextBoxes but not into the other one!

So, what's the problem? And How can I solve it?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
This is a capture of the form, empty fields should have data like other fields!:

https://imgur.com/bSvlk6d

**EDIT2:**

I'm openning the form like this:

```
private void mnuEmailSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fms = new frmMailSettings())
        {
            fms.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
```

The code to load data from settings is inside a procedure `LoadData()` which resides in from load. I'm closing the form by calling dispose AFTER saving data (I'm using another procedure `SaveData()`.

***I've updated the title to not 'loading' after I found that the data exists in `user.config` in Application's `AppData` folder.***

Comment: Are you sure that both settings are of user type?

Comment: Yes. everything has 'User' scope.

Comment: Can you add simple example of your current code? Maybe something going on elsewhere :)

Comment: @Reniuz, The only code in the form is like the code I've posted. Please note that I've uploaded a picture of the form.

Comment: No i mean show your code how you open form, when you loading texboxes and how you closing. Iam prety sure these lines you posted are good and form design is nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @Reniuz, I've updated the question and its title.

Comment: Still the main part is unknown. What do you mean closing form by calling dispose? Please add form content it will be much easier to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry to waste your time but I've found the problem, it's occurring earlier at `Program.cs`, there's a buggy code. Everything is fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Settings.Default` already, try to access the settings by name instead of accessing the setting by string key.

```
txtUsername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.email_username;
txtAddress.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.physical_address;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste your time, but I've found the problem.

At first I thought that Application is not SAVING data, but then after checking `user.config` I realized that data is saved correctly.

I forgot that I was doing something with the settings in `Program.cs`. Unfortunately the code was buggy and now everything is working!

Thank you!

Comment: I still suggest you access the settings by property name and not by key as suggested in my answer - far less error prone.